# Converting pcap format from LINKTYPE_LINUX_SSL to LINKTYPE_ETHERNET

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tshark

I am trying to parse a pcap file however I need the linktype to be of `LINKTYPE_ETHERNET`, whereas the current file I have is using `LINKTYPE_LINUX_SSL` (documentation here http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html)

Does anyone know if this could be a task I could complete using `tshark`, or am I going to have to hack something custom together to get the conversion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question has [been asked](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/21562/editcap-from-linux-cooked-capture-to-ethernet-packet) (and answered) before on the `wireshark`'s own version of stack overflow.  But I'll repeat it here with a little more detail.

A linux cooked socket (*SLL*, not to be confused with *SSL*) is used by `wireshark` when capturing on **all** interfaces.  It is a clever way to get around the fact that different interfaces have different MAC addresses.  The SLL format has no MAC address on the link layer, which is beneficial when capturing from several interfaces but a problem when trying to transform it into a link layer that has MAC addresses.

`tshark` definitely cannot do it.  `tshark` does not have the capability to change the format of a capture file.

`editcap` is `wireshark`'s capture file editor, which is the tool that shall be used to change the format of a capture file.  Still `editcap` only changes the file format, it cannot rewrite the packages themselves.  And what you're asking about is about rewriting the link layer.

Nothing that ships together with `wireshark` is capable of rewriting the link layer inside of a capture file.

---

What you need is the (appropriately named) `tcprewrite` utility, which ships in the [`tcpreplay` package](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/).  You need to add the MAC addresses on the command line to `tcprewrite`, both the source and destination addresses:

```
tcprewrite --dlt=enet --enet-dmac=52:54:00:11:11:11 \
    --enet-smac=52:54:00:22:22:22 -i in.pcap -o out.pcap
```

If you are confident that two devices are talking you can use the comma syntax of `--enet-dmac` and `--enet-smac`.

```
tcprewrite --dlt=enet --enet-dmac=52:54:00:11:11:11,52:54:00:22:22:22 \
    --enet-smac=52:54:00:22:22:22,52:54:00:11:11:11 -i in.pcap -o out.pcap
```

It is very likely that you want to use the second command, since it will look as a more believable `ethernet` conversation.

Most OSes have the `tcpreplay` in their package repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you have 16 byte long `LinuxSLL` header containing 6-byte MAC address followed by two unused bytes and two bytes of EtherType.

Hence, as long as you don't care for the sanity of destination MAC address in your resulting pcap file, you can chop those unused bytes with `editcap` and set Ethernet encapsulation type to, e.g.:

```
editcap -T ether -L -C 12:2 input-sll.pcap output-ether.pcap
```

And now `output-ether.pcap` contains valid Ethernet frames.